# Applying style dynamically

Tags: android, themes

I'd like to dynamically apply styles to my views at runtime.
Is there any method like View.setStyle(int style)?

Thanks

Comment: dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way at this time to set a Style dynamically. You might want to set all parameters for a style in one method and apply it to your View, but apart from that, there is no equivalent of a setStyle method. [Check here](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg22161.html) for full discussion.