# How add style in textView and editText from my code?

Tags: java, android, styles, textview, android-edittext

I create textView and editText in code.

```
           TextView textview = new TextView(getActivity());

            final EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
            editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

and i have style in res/values/mystyle
when i add style in textView it looks like this:

```
 TextView textview = new TextView(getActivity(), null,  R.style.editTextStyle);
```

But, nothing changed.
How add style in textView and editText from my code. What im doing wrong? 
 Thanks for all!

Comment: Yes you can set the style programmatically, see my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11436350/1221486

Answer (score 5):

We cannot programmatically set styles: [android set style in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code). At least not yet. The information in the style xml should me moved and converted into a layout xml format.

Basically you need to create a new layout xml, which contains only one view. Here's a sample layout for a `TextView`:

(layout/edit_text_style.xml in my test setup)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#000033"
    android:textColor="#00aa00"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

Then the `TextView` should be created in the `Activity` code using `getLayoutInflater()`. Here's sample code:

(MainActivity.java using layout/main.xml in my test setup.)

```java
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root); 
    TextView test = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edit_text_style, null); // Magic!
    test.setText("Ah, hello World..."); // Remove this if you set text in the xml
    root.addView(test); // Bang!
```

Here's also main.xml in my test setup:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/test"
        android:text="Absolutely meaningless and mostly harmless text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```