# Making an ListItem as Favourite in ExpandableListView

Tags: android

I am populating an ExpandableListView and when the user clicks on the item the child items open.
Can I have an child item named as favourite, when ever the user clicks on this list it will be favourite and the color of these listview changes after clicking on the favourite button.
How to achieve this, any help would be great.
Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use styles for changing the colours dynamically.  Set the style of the view from the code to change the same on the click.

Place any views in hidden state and enable and disable them on time according to ur requirement. For ex showing STAR for the favourite.

Comment: Please follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code