# Inflate style on android View on Runtime

Tags: android

Want to create views on runtime but i want to already define styles of the views on style.xml . Example:

```
<resources>


    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>

    <style name="DJV_TextField_Style" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_line_border</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
        <item name="android:cursorVisible">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:padding">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    </style>



</resources>
```

and i am creating the view like this on java :

```
new EditText(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.DJV_TextField_Style), null, 0, attrs, data);
```

this actually works but the width of the edittext still matches the screen when it is suppose to be 200dp.

custom_line_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="0dp"

            />

    <padding android:left="5dp"
             android:right="5dp"
             android:bottom="5dp"/>

    <stroke android:color="#777"

            android:width="2dp"/>

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>




</shape>
```

How do i fix this ?

Comment: This way may not support all the needed attributes. Do you want to try adding a layout resource with `<EditText>` top-level tag, specify all attributes and style, and then just inflate it using layout inflater? I usually prefer this way of creating views with complex formatting.

Comment: This might work (not tested though): `editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.DJV_TextField_Style), new XmlPullAttributes(XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newInstance())));`