# Android - How to programmatically set the button style in a Linearlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am programmatically creating a LinearLayout for an AlertDialog with some buttons.

I **WANT** to do this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
style="@android:style/ButtonBar">
```

But with code like this:

```
LinearLayout buttons = new LinearLayout(parentContext);
buttons.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonsParams =
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
topLayout.addView(buttons, buttonsParams);
buttons.setLayoutParams(buttonsParams);
Button btnAdd = new Button(context);
btnAdd.setText("Add");
```

How can I set the style of the buttons (use a button bar) programmitically?

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible. You can only add style programatically to text span.

Comment: Probably this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view

Comment: don't work
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Hope I'm not too late to join the party :)

Well, *Styles* can be applied to a `View` at initialization phase. For example:

```
LinearLayout button = new LinearLayout(context, null, android.R.style.ButtonBar);
```

Comment: This works only from API Level 11, don't you know how to do it in older APIs?

Comment: @Oliv I believe its not possible for older APIs. However, as an alternate, I would suggest you to Define your `LinearLayout` as an XML with all the styling you want and simply **inflate** that XML to an object inside your code.

Comment: If I change `Button` to `LinearLayout`, I loose other methods on Button class like  setText()

Comment: Doesn't work for me. As a result a button has no style at all and looks like flat text

Answer (score 56):

This worked for me:

```
int buttonStyle = R.style.your_button_style;
Button button = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, buttonStyle), null, buttonStyle)
```

Answer (score 18):

This is the only answer that actually delivered what I was looking for: http://belencruz.com/2013/04/set-styles-programmatically-in-android/

Essentially, create a layout XML file that simply has a `<Button/>` element with the style you want. Then, inflate it programmatically and just customize the button text.

Something along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button style="@style/your_custom_style_here"/>
```

In code:

```
Button button = (Button)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_custom_button_layout_file, null);
button.setText("Your Text");
```

Comment: This doesn't change the style for me

Comment: Thanks! Apparently the only working solution. Using `ContextThemeWrapper` or specifying the styles in the Button constructor do not apply all of the attributes.

Answer (score 10):

The [Paris](https://github.com/airbnb/paris) library from AirBnB is perfect for this, allowing for programmatic configuration like so:

```
Paris.styleBuilder(textView)
        .add(R.style.MyGreenTextView)
        .textSizeRes(R.dimen.my_text_size_small)
        .apply();
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of waqaslams

```
LinearLayout button = new LinearLayout(context, null, android.R.style.ButtonBar);
```

(which is, judging by the comments, API dependable) I have also read ridoys answer from here 
[ [Android Button Styling Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386556/android-button-styling-programatically) ] which is

```
transferBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.buttonstyle);
```

(exposing the above answers because one of these may also work for you, depending of API version you use),

**But this is what worked for me** (mind the change from "layout" to "drawable")**:**

```
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_custom_green);
```

(answer from [[How to programmatically setting style attribute in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view]))

Answer (score 3):

In my case style was not loaded at all when I pass them into `Button` constructor.
It seems that was because I was using the material design view. Here what solved my case:

```
val themeWrapper = ContextThemeWrapper(
      context,
      R.style.AppTheme_ButtonPrimary // my button style
)

val button = MaterialButton(themeWrapper)
```

Please note that `MaterialButton` was created instead of `Button`.

I found this solution at: [How to specify a style for a view programmatically in Android](https://medium.com/@omegasoft7/how-to-specify-a-style-for-a-view-programmatically-in-android-bba8622da173).