# Android : Setting textview background in 'style' in XML

Tags: android

Currently, am setting the background of a TextView using code like this:

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rect_with_border_grey);
```

I then came to know about dimens.xml usage and how you can set  through that file. Is it possible to set the background through ? i.e. I want to do the above code line through XML. Any help please?

I wouldn't do this using layout xml file as @Opiatefuchs pointed out (in the comment below). B'cos, this textview's background will change depending on the user setting in the App dynamically.

Comment: Just add attribute for TextView style:"@drawable/rect_with_border_grey"

Comment: what about to set the textViews background in the layout xml? dimens.xml is just, like the name said, for dimensions not style. To set a style for a view, there is a styles.xml

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I wouldn't do it with layout xml b'cos, this textview's background will change depending on the user setting in the App dynamically

Comment: if You want to set it programmatically, it is not possible like this with a style. This what You have done seems to be the only way, or You could create a custome view. For that, look here: Blundells answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723881/android-set-view-style-programatically

Answer (score 1):

Make a style like

```
<style name="MyTextStyle">
 Do everything you want to do with your TextView here.
</style>
```

and then assign that style to your textview in xml like this

```
style="@style/MyTextStyle"
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

dimen.xml is only use for giving dimension only. for setting background you need to do it with either layout xml file or from java.

Its up-to the requirement of setting background.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that you cannot set the background of a TextView via  element (i.e. XML) in Android. You need to use layout XML. But, in my case, I cannot use layout since the background will change dynamically based on user choice in the App.

Answer (score -1):

create dimens.xml file like this:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="paddingTop">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="paddingRight">20dp</dimen>
    ...
</resources>
```

then use it in your layout xml files like this:

```
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/paddingTop"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/paddingRight"
```