# How to use AttributeSet with Style defined

Tags: android, view

I am not sure how to create this view programmatically, I need a divider as styled for the width of the screen. The following not drawing anything, I am not sure how to use the AttributeSet here. Please help.

Thank you

```
    //in style.xml
<style name="Divider">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
</style>

 //in code
 View view = new View(activity, AttributeSetHere, R.style.Divider);
LinearLayout containerLL = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(mContainerViewId);
containerLL.addView(view);
```

Comment: how are you using that view.. because there you're just creating it.. you're not setting it to anything.

Comment: I added 2 lines of code so that it is more clear how I am using this "view"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty common question. You cant really apply a style like that. Although, I understand the desirability of such an API.
[These](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/P6vfKr5tqlY/X6204pvErjIJ) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723881/android-set-view-style-programatically) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code) will provide some explanation.

But what you are trying to achieve is possible with a background on a view.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
```

**Edited to add an example:**
Define a style in the file *`res/values/styles.xml`*

```
<style name="example_divider">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:layerType">software</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
</style>
```

then add this one line to the parent layout file

```
<View style="@style/example_divider" />
```

This will add the view to the parent layout file.

**Doing this in code**
Create a layout file that can be inflated at runtime. Lets name it *`res/layout/divider_layout.xml`*.

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      style="@style/example_divider" />
```

Then in java land, you can inflate the layout file *`res/layout/divider_layout.xml`* and add it to any parent Layout.

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.divider_layout, null, false);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 3);
LinearLayout containerLL = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(mContainerViewId);
containerLL.addView(view);
```

Comment: what would be the correct way to use this view in multiple location in different layout files? in xml and programmatically added to a container ViewGroup