# How to set switch button style in runTime?

Tags: android, uiswitch

I would like to change the style for one switch button

This is the xml code,

```
<Switch
 android:id="@+id/switch
 style="@style/switchStyle"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
/>
```

but I want to do this with code:

```
Switch newSwitch = new Switch(context);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL); 

viewHolder.switchButton = newSwitch;       
viewHolder.switchButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Can you use setBackgroundResource() ?

Comment: @Pol setBackgroundResource() receives a drawable. I want to set one style

Answer (score 0):

If you try to set params, you need to set the style again.

this might be useful :
[Android: set view style programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723881/android-set-view-style-programatically)