# Apply Style to MaterialButton programmatically

Tags: android, android-button, android-theme, android-styles, material-components-android

I'm trying to create a custom view extending from `MaterialButton` and apply style in code so I don't need to do it in xml.

```
class CustomRedButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, 
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null, 
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : MaterialButton(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ButtonRedStyle), attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

Style is:

```
<style name="ButtonRedStyle" 
    parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/red</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="strokeColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Everything works fine but `backgroundTint` property. For some reason background color is not changing, and it has Theme's primary color. However, if I try to apply the style to a `MaterialButton` in xml it does change the color.

Any idea why that can be happening or how I can achieve it?

Comment: Which `AppTheme` you're using? if it's `AppCompat` theme, try changing it to `MaterialComponents` once.

Comment: I'm using `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm also facing the same issue. The only workaround I've found so far is to set the tint programmatically like:

```
button.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing that too. Not the nicest way, but it does work.

Comment: This is not the right answer for the 'Apply Style to MaterialButton programmatically' question, setting a backtuondTintList it's a hack. This should be the right answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63221217/1944237

Answer (score 18):

Using

```
MaterialButton(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ButtonRedStyle), attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

you are applying a **themeoverlay** to default style, you are **not** applying a different style.

It means:

```
<style name="ButtonRedTheme" parent="...">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/...</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

If you want to apply a **different style** you have to:

- Define a custom attribute in `attrs.xml`

```xml
    <attr name="myButtonStyle" format="reference"/>
```

- Assing a style to this attribute in your app theme:

```xml
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <item name="myButtonStyle">@style/CustomButtonStyle</item>
   </style>
```

- Define the custom style:

```xml
    <style name="CustomButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.*">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/...</item>
        <item name="rippleColor">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="strokeWidth">1dp</item>
        <item name="strokeColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

Finally use:

```
val customButton = MaterialButton(context, null, R.attr.myButtonStyle)
```

Answer (score 2):

For a `TextButton` there shouldn't be a background (just the text has a color). For a colored button, you should use the default *Filled Button* style which is `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`.

And when applied as a theme, the button uses different attributes. It's described in section **Themed Attribute Mapping** here: https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/

```
Filled button
+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| Component Attribute    | Default Theme Attribute Value           |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| android:textAppearance | textAppearanceButton                    |
| android:textColor      | colorOnPrimary                          |
| iconTint               | colorOnPrimary                          |
| rippleColor            | colorOnPrimary at 32% opacity (pressed) |
| iconTint               | colorOnPrimary                          |
| backgroundTint         | colorPrimary                            |
| ...                    | ...                                     |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

In your case, the theme should look something like:

```xml
<style name="ButtonRedTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

You can also change all buttons to a specific style with

```xml
<item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/ButtonRedTheme</item>
```

in your app theme.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your style for **`CustomView`**, you've to pass it to constructor by passing it into third param **`defStyleAttr`** like this:

```
class CustomRedButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, 
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null, 
    defStyleAttr: Int = R.style.ButtonRedStyle // Just default style like this
) : MaterialButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

and you can initialize it like this programmatically,

```
CustomRedButton(this, null, R.style.ButtonRedStyle) // Initialization, ('this' is context)
```

For more details refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21043373/10271334)

Comment: That, for some reason, is not working for MaterialButtons. None of the parameters in the style is used. To make it work I needed to use the `ContextThemeWrapper`.

Comment: The 3rd attribute is a style attribute defined in the app theme, is **not** a style.

Comment: This does not work for MaterialButton. Using `ContextThemeWrapper` does at least partially work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a simple use case, i need to update the button `backgroundTint` and `isEnabled` state
what i did:
i created a custom class that extends from MaterialButton

```
class MyCustomMaterialButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : MaterialButton(context, attrs)
```

then i added an extension to this class to update button styling attributes:

```
fun MyCustomMaterialButton.updateEnabledState(enabled: Boolean){
    apply {
        if(enabled){
            isEnabled = true
            setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary))
        }
        else{
            isEnabled = false
            setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary_warm_grey_five))
        }
    }
}
```

this is how it looks like in Xml:

```
   <com.karny.branding.KarnyMaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/smsAuthButton"
        style="@style/PrimaryButtonDisabled"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="@string/sms_auth_check"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/left_middle_guide_line"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/right_middle_guide_line"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/smsAuthNumberContainer" />
```