# How to set a theme to a customView?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, styles, themes

I have this `style.xml`:

```
<style name="header_has_selected_account" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>

<item name="android:layout_marginStart">
  @dimen/account_menu_account_list_item_avatar_margin_end
</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginEnd">
  @dimen/account_menu_account_list_item_margin_end
</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginLeft">
  @dimen/account_menu_account_list_item_avatar_margin_end
</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginRight">
  @dimen/account_menu_account_list_item_margin_end
</item>
  </style>
```

I have a `CustomView` with a layout with two `TextViews` and an `ImageView`.

How can I set the style to only one of the `TextViews` (not custom `TextView`)? Do I have to create 2 `CustomView` and a custom ImageView as I have to pass the style throw their `ctor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create new custom views. If you have the reference to your `TextView` all you need to use is the `TextViewCompat` to apply a certain style resource.

Like this:

```
TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(yourTextView, yourStyleId);
```

**Note:**
`TextViewCompat` is available on `android.support.v4`.

---

From the documentation:

> Sets the text appearance from the specified style resource.

Comment: and how can i change just the ImageView size?

Comment: ImageView is not so easy. You can either instantiate your view with the style you want: new ImageView(context, null, R.style.Your_Style_Resource);.
Or through a custom view. Check the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11723881/1574250