# Cannot set style to LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, styles, android-linearlayout, programmatically-created

I'm trying to set style to programmatically created LinearLayout this way:

(Reference: [Android: set view style programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723881/android-set-view-style-programmatically#answer-21043373))

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this, null, R.style.linear_container);
```

And styles.xml

```
<style name="linear_container">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#9B1212</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
</style>
```

But style is not applied how to make it work?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol ContextThemeWrapper

Comment: working now but margin, width and height are not set!!

Comment: so how can i add margin to the item programmatically? i tried many solutions but nothing worked for me. would you help me with this please?

Comment: added the question here please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207828/android-how-to-set-linearlayout-marging-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

you can set layout params as below:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: @PHP User got it?

Comment: @PHP User any doubts?

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to set your styles programmatically would be to use the [paris](https://github.com/airbnb/paris) library from Airbnb.
After implementing the library correctly it's as easy as

```
myView.style(R.style.MyStyle)
```