# Android: How to set LinearLayout marging programmatically

Tags: android, margins, programmatically-created

I've been trying to set margins for a programmatically created LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
setMargins(linearLayout,20,20,20,20);

   private void setMargins (View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

        final float scale = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        // convert the DP into pixel
        int l =  (int)(left * scale + 0.5f);
        int r =  (int)(right * scale + 0.5f);
        int t =  (int)(top * scale + 0.5f);
        int b =  (int)(bottom * scale + 0.5f);

        p.setMargins(l, t, r, b);
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

But it didn't work so I tried this from another answer here

```
parameter =  (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
parameter.setMargins(leftMargin, parameter.topMargin, parameter.rightMargin, parameter.bottomMargin); // left, top, right, bottom
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(parameter);
```

But I get "Cannot solve symbol parameter"

How can I set margins to programmatically created view?

Comment: Did you initialize parameter? LinearLayout.LayoutParams parameter =...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```