# Is it possible to change MaterialButton's style "on fly"?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

Android 6.0, Android Studio 3.5

In my android project , in my xml layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonStartSearchBluetooth"
            style="@style/buttonEnableStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
            android:onClick="onClickButtonStartSearch"
            android:text="@string/start_search"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

my styles:

```
 <style name="buttonEnableStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_states_materialbuttons</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/color_states_materialbutton</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/byttonTexAppearanceStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="buttonClickStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_bg_color</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/button_click_bg_color</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/byttonTexAppearanceStyle</item>
    </style>
```

When click on this button I want to change  style from `buttonEnableStyle` to `buttonClickStyle` "on fly". Is it possible to do this programmaticaly?

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723881/android-set-view-style-programmatically