# How to set EditText style from styles.xml in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, android-styles

I'm generating `EditText` fields and wish to set it's style from **styles.xml** file. But can't manage to do it. I can set some parameters, but I would rather use a style from styles.xml so it would be easier to change later if needed.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="input_fields_single_line">
<item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/input_field_shape</item>
<item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
</style>
```

**Java code:**

```
 List<EditText> inputFieldList = new ArrayList<EditText>();
public void generateInputFields() {
   EditText editTextFieldTitle = new EditText(this);
    inputFieldList.add(editTextFieldTitle); 
    editTextFieldTitle.setHint(R.string.enter_field_title);
    editTextFieldTitle.setMaxLines(1);
    editTextFieldTitle.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    editTextFieldTitle.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    editTextFieldTitle.requestFocus();
    myLayout.addView(editTextFieldTitle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a separate style for the EditText like what you are doing but parented with the Widget.EditText like the following:

```
<style name="MyCustomeEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    ...add as many items as you need
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/input_field_shape</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
</style>
```

Then call your style inside each edit text in the xml like the following:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/MyCustomeEditTextStyle" />
```

BUT if you are want it to be globally set once and set without the xml because you are generating your EditText programmatically like this:

```
EditText editTextFieldTitle = new EditText(this);
```

you can then set your style in the application style like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/YourParentTheme">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/MyCustomeEditTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I was looking for something like this.

editTextFieldTitle = new EditText(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,R.style.input_fields_single_line)); 

BUt it doesn't work For Some reason

Comment: In the question you said: "I'm generating EditText fields and wish to set its style from styles.xml resource file. But can't manage to do it"

Comment: Can you please clarify more which part of the EditText you want to set style for from the styles.xml

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution. I had to put 3 arguments in the constructor

Comment: happy to hear that

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here. [Android: set view style programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723881/android-set-view-style-programmatically)

```
editTextFieldTitle = new EditText(new ContextThemeWrapper(getBaseContext(),R.style.input_fields_single_line),null,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a attribute in EditText called styles use that.and if you want to customize it than make own style in drawable , A new XML and link to the editText using styles attribute.