# How to set resource <style> programmatically in CustomButtonView class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-styles

I'm able to set styles via layout xml. But I just want to set these style programmatically at running time.Actually I have 3 styles in style.xml depending on condition or OnClick event I would like to change the Custombutton style(CustomButton's text, Background, padding like etc,,).

Please somebody assist me to complete this section.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't set styles programmatically.  Take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Style after creating a View programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820452/add-style-after-creating-a-view-programmatically)