# Change TabLayout Style programmatically

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have created a custom style for my tab layout in `styles.xml` file.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="NormalTabLayputTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/NormalTabLayputTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="NormalTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

I am able to use the style in my layout file as;

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/marketsTabs"
    style="@style/NormalTabLayputTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_viewpager_tab_height"
    app:paddingStart="1dp"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/view_pager_indicator_color"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/nintypercentblack"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/sixtypercentblack">
```

Everything works fine. But I want to change the style at runtime. I have gone through stackoverflow, but haven't found anything about this. Is it possible ?

I have tried making a `CustomTabLayout` class extending `TabLayout`, no success either.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820452/add-style-after-creating-a-view-programmatically