# Set view style programmatically Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, styles, themes, android-custom-view

I searched for many answers but didn't find any working solution. I wonder if there is some possibility to set Edittext style programmatically. In my situation, I have one layout which is included and used in two different places and beside the place where it is included need to use a different style.

```
<style name="TestStyle1" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:maxLength">1</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>

<style name="TestStyle2" parent="CodeTextStyle">
    <item name="android:alpha">0.5</item>
</style>
```

first_activity.xml

```
  <include
        layout="@layout/custom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

second_activity.xml

```
  <include
        layout="@layout/custom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

custom_layout.xml

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        app:style_ref="@style/CustomTextStyle"
        style="@style/TestStyle1" <-- Here i need to change style beside of usage
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CustomEditText.kt

```
class CustomEditText @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) : AppCompatEditText(context, attrs) {

init {
    val typedArray = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomEditText, 0 , 0)
    try {

        val style2 = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomEditText_style_ref, 0)

        setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, style2)
        invalidate()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there any Kotlin code you have tried so far? What does this have to do with data-binding? The only option I am seeing is to create a custom LinearLayout → CustomLayout and put the respective style attributes in the constructor.

Comment: @nulldroid sorry I miss adding my custom class

Answer (score 2):

So the simplest way, if your min API level is 23 would be to get a reference of each CustomEditText instance after inflation of the respective activity layout, then just set

```
myCustomEditText.setTextAppearance(R.style.TestStyle1)
```

as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50785619/11278807) (which is using the deprecated version of this)

Another option would be to apply the 2 styles to two respective app theme styles, which you can set to each activity in AndroidManifest.

Or you can go  the more complicated path that I suggested in my comment: 
Create a custom LinearLayout class and pass the style in the constructor:

```
class CustomLayout(context: Context) : LinearLayout(context, null, R.style.TestStyle1)
```

You would just need to figure out a way to let the layout know which activity it is created. As far as I know, that style would then get passed on to each child view, your CustomEditText respectively.

Comment: How would you set this on a `Button`?

Comment: A Button is just another View that also features text. So the same?

Answer (score 0):

Two useful answers.

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template, null);
```

or

```
int buttonStyle = R.style.your_button_style;
Button button = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, buttonStyle), null, buttonStyle).
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24438579/5093308 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/5488652/5093308