# How can I set style to disabled button in Android?

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles, material-components-android

I have this button, style and color states file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button1"
    style="@style/btnGreen"/>
```

```
<style name="btnGreen" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/color_states_btn_green</item>
</style>
```

Color states: `color_states_btn_green.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#00FF00" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:alpha="0.10" android:color="#00FF00"/>
</selector>
```

Goal is:
Button enabled => enabled style of `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`
Button disabled => disabled style of `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton`

I need something like this (pseudocode):

```
<selector>
    <item style="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton" android:state_enabled="false"/>
</selector>
```

How can I achieve this? **I do not change button attributes programmatically**, because there is problem to switch between Day & Night without recreating. Thank you.

Comment: Why dont you use `onClick()` on button to change shape of button?

Comment: `you can't change styles programmatically; you can set the look of a screen, or part of a layout, or individual button in your XML` from [Christopher Orr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234938/christopher-orr)...

Comment: You can't change style in this way, but you can change all the attributes you need.

Comment: I do not change button attributes programmatically, because there is problem to switch between Day & Night without recreating.

Answer (score 1):

**XML:**

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/BSAMPLE"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:background="#4B5E6E"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:text="ENABLED"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="switchClicked"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="300dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="7dp" />
```

**res>values>styles.xml:**

```
<style name="btnGreen" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Buttonenabled" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@style/btnGreen</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:enabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:alpha">0.10</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonDisabled" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="android:background">@style/btnGreen</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:enabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:alpha">0.10</item>
    </style>
```

Then by program,

```
  public void switchClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((Switch) view).isChecked();
        String str = "";

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.sw:
                if (checked){
                    view.setClickable(false);
                    view.setBackgroundColor(R.style.btnGreen);

                }
                else{
                    view.setClickable(false);
                    view.setBackgroundColor(R.style.btnGreen);
                   }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do not change only backgroundColor. I want to change style from `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` to `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton` when button is disabled.

Comment: What will this style attribute do to that button?

Comment: Change style [https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons#outlined-button](https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons#outlined-button)

Comment: set an ONCLICK attribute in <Button> Tag in XML file like above

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61929320/13031115) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2016344/13031115) Second link deals exactly your issue.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I do not change button attributes programmatically, because there is problem to switch between Day & Night without recreating. I want to **change style, when button is disabled by XML**.

Comment: Then use validation in program if(BUTTON.isClickable()) in onCreate() and then call switchclicked() in if statement