# Android TableRow change font size to content

Tags: android, textview, tablerow

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour with textviews hosted into a `TableRow`: it looks like as they are rendered using the a smaller font than the rest of the app.

I KNOW that it's better to use an XML and inflate it, so it's what I'm going to do next, but now I am just curious to understand what's happening...

I have an XML with a `TableLayout`. Inside there is a `TableRow`. Inside the `TableRow`, a `TextView`. I have defined a style to have all the `TextView` in my app using the `textAppearanceMedium` style. It works.
Now, I add new `TableRow` (each one with its own `TextView`) programmatically: what happens is that all the `TextView` in the new rows are using a smaller font then the first one. And even if I explicitly set the `textAppearanceMedium`, nothing happens.

It must be something obvious. What I'm missing?

Thx all in advance.

Comment: How are you applying the style programmatically when you add the TextViews?

Comment: @KenWolf

txtChild2.setTextAppearance(getBaseContext(), attr.textAppearanceLarge);

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a style programmatically. My guess is your style is not applying when you are creating everything in code.

Read this here: [android set style in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code)

The fix is, as you hinted at, to set the style in XML and inflate the objects from XML programmatically and then add them as needed.

Comment: This sound reasonable so no problem with it. Still, I cannot understand why the newly created TextView do not inherits the app theme.

Comment: Just make it in XML and it will work. I didn't write Android, I just code in it :)

Comment: Lol. I understand your pov, but I really hate to not know why things happens :-D

Comment: This is from the Android development team: (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/P6vfKr5tqlY/X6204pvErjIJ) but they don't really explain it.