# Display progressdialog without text Android

Tags: android, progressdialog

Android 2.3.3

I have a progressdialog that shows, Loading.. as text. Here is the code for the progressdialog .

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);      
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();
```

If I remove the line `progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");`, I get a progressdialog of the left and an empty box on the right that occupies the width of the parent.

I want to display only the progressdialog , aligned at the center. Please refer to the images below..

This is what i have...

[image]

This is what i want...

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try this 1.create a method like this :

```
public static ProgressDialog createProgressDialog(Context context) {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    try {
        dialog.show();
    } catch (BadTokenException e) {

    }
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.getWindow()
        .setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);
    // dialog.setMessage(Message);
    return dialog;
}
```

// Xml Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and call this method wherever you want :

```
if (progressDialog == null) {
    progressDialog = Utils.createProgressDialog(Login.this);
    progressDialog.show();
} else {
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I get the following crash/error: "requestFeature() must be called before adding content"

Comment: i tried all the solutions offered. this one is the best. it shows a nice clean progress spinner without a box and without text.

Comment: At least in Lollipop, the spinner does show a box for me, with the typical width and background colour of a dialog.

Comment: The solution for Lollipop is to run the following before setContentView: dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

Comment: @all ->> see my answer below <<--

Answer (score 23):

If you happen to get the **error** : "`requestFeature() must be called before adding content`", the solution is to call `progressDialog.show()` BEFORE you call `progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog)`.

Comment: superb @Choletski

Answer (score 8):

Working and looking good on material design with accent color (if you have them)

Tried hard to make it work on both 5.0+ and lower API version. And the solution is to make it with a dialog instead of a progress.

in layout folder create a file **aux_progress_spinner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Create a function somewhere...let's say **Utils.class**

```
   public static Dialog LoadingSpinner(Context mContext){
        Dialog pd = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Black);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.aux_progress_spinner, null);
        pd.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        pd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent);
        pd.setContentView(view);
        return pd;
    }
```

**In your fragment/activity call:**

```
 private Dialog progress_spinner;
 progress_spinner = Utils.LoadingSpinner(mContext);   

 //------ Where you want it ------
 progress_spinner.show();

 //------- Dismiss it --------
 progress_spinner.dismiss();
```

**Optional:** add a simple CountDownTimer to test how it looks

```
        new CountDownTimer(1000,1000){

            @Override public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override public void onFinish() {
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();
```

Answer (score 7):

you can add below style in your style.xml

```
<style name="progress_bar_style">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

where you add any color in color.xml file.

Comment: @VamsiChalla you want style to write programmatically java code ? or you want how to use this style in java code ?

Comment: I want to do whatever the above xml code does, programmatically with java code. I want to style the progressdialog programmatically.

Comment: first way you use Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext,"your stylename"); or other you can check style programmatilly set by code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code

Comment: @BenH what is your requirment ? we can set by programmatically or by style

Comment: my requirement is the same as the OP's. a spinner without a box around it, and centered.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
Progress progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE);
```

If necessary, add to Gradle dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
```

Comment: it shows a black square in progress dialog background with your method, although I have setBackgroundDrawable as transparent, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use ProgressBar instead of ProgressDialog.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: Use the style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle" in xml

Comment: Try setting the layout parameters programatically. I'm not sure about this though.

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

`progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);`

and if you want no title you can :

```
progressDialog.setTitle(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

MuraliGanesan's answer is correct, but I use just Dialog, not ProgressDialog to avoid "requestFeature() must be called before adding content" exception

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by just creating one class which extends Dialog class:

Let's say I have created below class:

```
public class TransparentProgressDialog extends Dialog {

    public ImageView iv;

    public TransparentProgressDialog(Context context, int resourceIdOfImage) {
        super(context, R.style.TransparentProgressDialog);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlmp = getWindow().getAttributes();
        wlmp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        getWindow().setAttributes(wlmp);
        setTitle(null);
        setCancelable(false);
        setOnCancelListener(null);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        iv = new ImageView(context);
        iv.setImageResource(resourceIdOfImage);
        layout.addView(iv, params);
        addContentView(layout, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
        anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim.setDuration(3000);
        iv.setAnimation(anim);
        iv.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

Put `TransparentProgressDialog` in style.xml:

@null
        @android:color/transparent
        true
        @null
        @null
        @android:style/Animation.Dialog
        stateUnspecified|adjustPan
        true
        @android:color/transparent

Now you can put any progress image which will circulate:

```
TransparentProgressDialog pDialog = new TransparentProgressDialog(mContext, R.drawable.progress);
pDialog.show();
```

That's it.

Comment: can you show me the style for the progress dialog? please :D

Answer (score 1):

Based on MuraliGanesan answer I created a subclass of progressDialog.

```
public class LoadingDialog extends ProgressDialog {

    public LoadingDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        setCancelable(false);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);
    }
}
```

Also you have to create the custom_progress_dialog.xml in res/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And you use it as easy as this:

```
LoadingDialog dialog = new LoadingDialog(this);
dialog.show();
:
:
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me in MonoDroid:

```
progressDialog.SetMessage((string)null);
```

Try this in java:

```
progressDialog.setMessage(null);
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue; the icon still appears on the left and the rest of the dialog is blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog.show(this, null,"", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is..

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private void loadProgressDialog() {
    try {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (progressDialog != null && !progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}


private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI6S5.jpg)