# Create a progressDialog only with the spinner (in the middle)

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-progressbar

I need to create a progressDialog only with the spinner and without the box (or at least with a smaller box and the image in the middle).

I don't want to add a spinner to my .xml (layout file) to load the spinner.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31673756/1031297

Answer (score 95, accepted):

try this way:

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(Login.this,R.style.MyTheme);
pd.setCancelable(false);
pd.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
pd.show();
```

And create **Theme** in `values\styles.xml`

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

And also add this **Theme** in `values\styles.xml`

```
 <style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And add `values\colors.xml`

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

Comment: how to change progress circle color

Comment: To change color of circle of progress dialog you can use :   ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null,null);
ProgressBar spinner = new android.widget.ProgressBar(MainActivity.this, null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);
        spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#53CBF1"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                                       dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setContentView(spinner);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();

Answer (score 6):

Just single line code :

```
pd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: How to get the circle in middle of the window?

Comment: @hetsgandhi If you want to customize whole progress dialog then just extends Dialog and create your own view. By the way progress dialog is now deprecated.

Comment: So what should be used other than any library?

Comment: @hetsgandhi Use ProgressBar. If you want to disable touch then you can set flags to window: window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)
and enable touch using : window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE)