# Android: Spinning ProgressDialog - How?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Using following code:

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(activity);
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
pd.show();
```

This shows spinning progress wheel, but it has a rectangle with white spaces on both sides.

I only need the spinning wheel, nothing else. 
And also possibly style it better.

Comment: Look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751662/create-a-progressdialog-only-with-the-spinner-in-the-middle/21751886#21751886](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751662/create-a-progressdialog-only-with-the-spinner-in-the-middle/21751886#21751886)

Comment: MD> That did not work... I deviated only in putting the transparent color value in color.xml file instead of colors.xml (since colors.xml was not there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ProgressDialog` to `ProgressBar` and put it in the layout where you want to have it:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/spinningProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</ProgressBar>
```

Set the visibility as you wish in your activity / fragment.

Comment: Gender> Thanks.. but I would prefer not do anything in layouts... is there a way to do this programatically only?

Comment: You can, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395769/how-to-programmatically-add-views-to-views
Can I ask you why do you want to do it programmatically?

Comment: Grender> I went with your sugested solution .. works well! Do you know how to style the spinner better.. i.e make it a bit colorful etc.?

Comment: Hello Jasper, if you want to style the spinner, the most easy way is to use some libraries, you can check this library for example:
https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel