# Design ProgressDialog java

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I need to make a simple progress dialog with a square with only a circle inside
[image]

like this but on an dark back ground. 50x50 dp.

I tried this. But my app is crashes on the show()
[Display progressdialog without text Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980404/display-progressdialog-without-text-android)

here is my code : 
utils.java

```
protected void startLoading() {
        ProgressDialog proDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getActivity()); 
        proDialog.setCancelable(false);
        proDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);
        proDialog.show();
    }
```

.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: u want to make it in java or android?

Comment: no need to create this in xml....

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: log : 10-18 12:28:26.924: E/AndroidRuntime(809): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer :

need to switch between

> proDialog.show();

and then to set Content.

> proDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);

Answer (score 0):

`og : 10-18 12:28:26.924: E/AndroidRuntime(809): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content`

This is not because of your `progressBar`.

You probably are calling a `requestFeature` method (for hiding your windowBar, for making your app fulscreen or something else) after your `setContentLayout` in your `onCreate` method. Please, put this call before your `setContentLayout` and this would work ;)

Comment: i don't have a requestFeature(). also if i remove "proDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);" the progress dialog appear but not look as i want it to be.