# Put View styles in resource files

Tags: android, android-styles

I have some customized Views like:

```
public class CustomizedTextView extends TextView {
...
    public CustomizedTextView(Context context) {
        this.setText(TEXT_COLOR);
        this.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE);
        this.setTypeFace(TYPE_FACE);
        this.setPadding(LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM);
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, these style settings and corresponding constants takes many lines of code. So I want to separate it out in resource files.

I have gone through the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), it says you could defined a style file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But I didn't find an API like setStyle(R.style.style001) to set the style in code. I also found a post here: [android set style in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code)

Basically it says you can't do it in code. However this post is three years ago I am not sure what's the situation in API 19. Because defining a customized View is so common in Android that I don't understand why this is not possible.

Comment: Are you creating this view in xml or code when you add it to your app?

Comment: @dcharms I am creating it in the code. I know how to add style with xml but don't know how to add it with code.

Comment: You can use setTextAppearance from code to set the style. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can set the textview style using `setTextAppearance` like this

```
  textView.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.CodeFont);
```