# How to set Preference preferenceInformationStyle from code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

A preference style can be set like this:

```
<Preference
    android:key="my_pref"
    style="?android:preferenceInformationStyle" />
```

Is there a way to apply the same style dynamically from Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set a view's style programmatically.
Probably below solution will help: [android set style in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code)