# Set listSeparatorTextViewStyle in Code

Tags: android

In XML it's easy to set `listSeparatorTextViewStyle`:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>
```

But how do I set the `style` attribute in java?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `style` attribute at runtime. You must set the style before the view is created i.e. at compile time in your xml.

However you can somewhat achieve it by `setTextAppearance` or `setTextTypeface`.

Even if this doesn't help then there is a workaround to do this explained on the link mentioned below :

[android set style in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code)

If you just want a divider then simply use this below your `TextView` :

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/grey"/>
```

Comment: So it's impossible to create ListSeperators at runtime?

Comment: @haansn08 Updated answer. Have a look. it'll definitely solve your issue.