# Android Fragment/Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog

I have 1 Class that are opened two different ways. One way is it's opened from a sliding drawer and another way is as a dialog. Below you can see both of them. However, you can see that the `edittext` does not look the same in both. How can I modify the dialog style to look like the fragment?

Here is how it is made:

```
final EditText editTextView = new EditText(a); 
editTextView.setHint(R.string.hintNote); 
editTextView.setTag(tag); editTextView.setId(_id);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the code for both of the editText

Comment: @royB `1 Class, and 1 XML layout that are opened two different ways` as i stated they are both exactly the same, the only way they are different is how they are opened.

Comment: so add the code...There is no reason that the EditText will look different if it has the exact same properties.  in short if you will add a code it will be easier to help you

Comment: `final EditText editTextView = new EditText(a);
editTextView.setHint(R.string.hintNote);
editTextView.setTag(tag);
editTextView.setId(_id);` there ya go

Comment: Didn't you say that you are using xml?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. The question and been edited already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the style attribute to the layout XML. They will both then use the style specified:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
```

Comment: Thanks Randy, Sorry i forgot to mention this particular item is built programmatically not through xml (I edited my question to reflect this).

Comment: In that case you may want to look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code

Which says to inflate a template view. Just create a bare minimum xml layout with your edittext view and it's style attribute. Then inflate that template view when you create your new edittext view programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know if there would be a way to do it without.