# How to apply style to dynamically created EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-styles

I have one Button, and **on every click of that button I want to create new EditText Dynamically.**

Now my question is , I have one style in **style.xml** for EditText. Now how can I apply that style  to this dynamically created EditText?

**My Code for EditText is:**

```
    List<EditText> allEdsLabReport ;
    String[] edsLabReport;
    EditText LabReportNm;

    AddMoreLabReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {

           LabReportNm = new EditText(CaseReport.this);

          allEdsLabReport.add(LabReportNm);

          TableLayout tbl2 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayoutLabReport);
          TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(CaseReport.this);

          tr1.addView(LabReportNm);
          tbl2.addView(tr1);

      }
        });
```

Comment: A lot of solution is available here check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code

Comment: I think Dynamic style change is not currently supported. You must set the style before the view is create (in xml).

Comment: I came to know that Dynamic style change is not currently supported. So there is no reason to remain this question open.

Comment: @cracker: karu j chu saheb!! by d way hws u?

Answer (score 5):

```
new EditText(new ContextThemeWrapper(CaseReport.this, R.style.my_style));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LabReportNm.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.style.xml)

editText.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.demo.xml);
```

Comment: It would be great if you provided more details to your answer :)

Comment: LabReportNm = new EditText(CaseReport.this); this is your edit text

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar yes .LabReportNm is my dynamically created EditText

Comment: LabReportNm.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.style.xml) and i also updated code please check

Comment: Please improve the quality of your post by explaining what you've done and why

Comment: use this LabReportNm = new EditText(CaseReport.this,,R.drawable.demo.xml);