# Setting button style programmatically

Tags: android, button, programmatically-created

I'm trying to create layout with buttons and spinners programmatically. I can't do this in xml, because number of spinners depends on certain parameters.

My question here is: how can i set button style from @style resources?
It just need to be set once, when layout is created.

My code for creating button (class: `DBsetupLayout`):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams doneButtonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    doneButton = new Button(this.context);
    doneButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 1);
    doneButton.setLayoutParams(doneButtonParams);
    doneButton.setText("DONE");
    doneButton.setId(2);
```

I haven't found any `addRule` options to add style.

MainActivity contains this code:

```
DBsetupLayout setupLayout = new DBsetupLayout(this, activityStatesNumber);
btdevSetupSaveButton = setupLayout.doneButton;
btdevSetupSaveButton.setOnClickListener...
```

I tried this: [android set style in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code), but it doesn't work for me, so i'm looking for some kind of other solution.

Any help appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set button background.

Using this code.

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_button_drawable);
```

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic style change is not currently supported. You must set the style before the view is create (in xml)