# Style not working entirely when applied on Button programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Here is my style:

```
<style name="buttonQuestionStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/questionButton</item>
</style>
```

And here my code:

```
Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
btn.setText(ojb.getText());
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
    btn.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.buttonQuestionStyle);
} else {
    btn.setTextAppearance(R.style.buttonQuestionStyle);
}
```

In the app:

Programmatically button appears like this:
[image: programmatically button]

And via layout it worked. Appears like this:
[image: xml layout button]

Here is my code in the XML Layout:

```
<Button
    android:text="Question"
    style="@style/buttonQuestionStyle" />
```

So... I dont know why it happens, and how fix it.

Comment: You cannot set a view's style programmatically yet, but you may find this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code) useful.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me

Answer (score 7):

You can pass a `ContextThemeWrapper` in constructor for button and use 3 arguments constructor for `Button(context, attributeset, defStyle)`.

```
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this,R.style.buttonQuestionStyle);
Button btn = new Button(wrapper, null, 0); // note this constructor
btn.setText("some text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Some info around why you cannot set button's style programmatically, as per the JavaDoc of method `setTextAppearance`

> ```
> Sets the text appearance from the specified style resource.
>  <p>
>  Use a framework-defined {@code TextAppearance} style like
>  {@link android.R.style#TextAppearance_Material_Body1    @android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Body1}
>  or see {@link android.R.styleable#TextAppearance TextAppearance} for the
>  set of attributes that can be used in a custom style.
>   @param resId the resource identifier of the style to apply
>  @attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_textAppearance
> ```

So it deals with only text appearance not other style elements.

Still if you want to apply some style at `runtime programmatically` you need to

1. make each and every change separately for example to set `background` you need to call `setBackground` and similarly for other cases.

   or
2. Inflate that `view` programmatically using that particular theme.