# Why is ContextThemeWrapper now restricted to the Support Library group?

Tags: android, syntax-error, android-support-library, android-context, android-lint

I started using a `ContextThemeWrapper` to apply a style dynamically to an `ImageButton`; based [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42706328/5115932) to another question of mine, and answers to other [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28613069/5115932) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442610/5115932).

```
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), mStyleRes);
mImageButton = new AppCompatImageButton(wrapper, null, 0);
```

But recently a lint error started appearing on the `ContextThemeWrapper` constructor stating:

> `ContextThemeWrapper` can only be called from within the same library
>   group (groupId=com.android.support)

I noticed that the class marked with the `@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)` annotation, which is causing the lint error to appear. But I cannot find any information as to *why* it is restricted to the `com.android.support` library group.

As far as I can tell, this is the only way to apply a style, theme or theme overlay to a `View` programmatically; other than setting a default style attribute as the third argument in the constructor. So I am wondering why its use would be restricted at all; is there some issue with using the class outside of the support libraries? Could there be side-effects that I am not aware of?

---

The only [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41150995/5115932) that I have come across is one about a (now fixed) bug; that caused this lint error to be displayed on the `onCreate` method of a subclass of `AppCompatActivity`. I do not think this occurrence is a bug, rather a deliberate restriction; which I would like to know the reasoning behind.

I should note; this restriction (as of now) actually seems to have no effect on the code using a `ContextThemeWrapper`. It compiles and runs fine, and works as I would expect it to.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[`android.view.ContextThemeWrapper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) != `android.support.v7.view.ContextThemeWrapper`.

The support library one is annotated `@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)`, and also `@hide` - it's not meant to be a public API.

The first one is public.

Comment: I see the same issue in `import android.support.v7.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatSet` but I can't find an alternative, any ideas?

Comment: @TheHebrewHammer `android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat`

Comment: just changing the import from 'support.v7.view' to 'android.view', sometimes solution is too easy than you think :) ha ha

Comment: I had to change it from `android.view.ContextThemeWrapper` to `androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper` to make a warning about unavailable on low API level disappear. The warning was **Call requires API level 23 (current min is 16): 'new android.view.ContextThemeWrapper'**