# Set TextInputLayout theme programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

Is there a way to change the theme of a TextInputLayout programmatically in Android. 
If I have the following TextInputLayout for ex.:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutTheme"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Could I somehow change this line `android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutTheme"` to another theme programmatically?

Comment: You may want to look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723881/android-set-view-style-programmatically

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is **no** way to change theme of any view or any layout at **runtime**. Because of themes and styles are applied during creation of view, recursively. (Themes also applies child views of layouts)

**But**, you can change that theme before creation of view using XML layout or programmatically.

#### Programmatically:

**Method 1** - Create `TextInputLayout` programmatically with wrapping `Context` with `android.view.ContextThemeWrapper` and use.

```
TextInputLayout layout = new TextInputLayout(new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style. TextInputLayoutTheme));
```

**Method 2** - Extend TextInputLayout and use your own layout. Pass `ContextThemeWrapper` as context.

```
public class MyTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
    public MyTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        super(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AppTheme));
    }

    public MyTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AppTheme), attrs);
    }

    public MyTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AppTheme), attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

Now, you can use `MyTextInputLayout` in your XML layout

#### With XML Layout:

**1)** In `attrs.xml` file, create new attribute named `textInputLayoutTheme`

```
<attr name="textInputLayoutTheme" format="reference"/>
```

**2)** In your `AppTheme` in `styles.xml` file set your `@style/TextInputLayoutTheme` as `textInputLayoutTheme`.

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="PARENT_THEME">
        <item name="textInputLayoutTheme">@style/TextInputLayoutTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Secondary">
        <item name="textInputLayoutTheme">@style/TextInputLayoutTheme_Secondary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**3)** In your `layout.xml` file, set `?attr/textInputLayoutTheme` as a `TextInputLayout` theme

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:theme="@?attr/textInputLayoutTheme"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Error">
```

Now, when you change your application theme from `AppTheme` to `AppTheme.Secondary` `TextInputLayoutTheme_Secondary` will be used as a theme of your `TextInputLayout` instead of `TextInputLayoutTheme`.

Comment: I have tried both methods of Programmatically. But not working.

Comment: You are using the `android.view.ContextThemeWrapper` right? Support libraries also have class named `ContextThemeWrapper` and restricted to use support libraries internal use only. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42814273/860189

Comment: I am using androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper;

Comment: Using xml it is working but I am facing issue when done with programmatically.

Comment: Ok, try with `android.view.ContextThemeWrapper` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the accepted answer is not working for me.

My solution was to wrap `TextInputLayout` in a custom layout.

`view_input_layout_wrapper.xml`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeMaterial"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

TextInputLayoutWrapper

```
class TextInputLayoutWrapper(context: Context) : FrameLayout(context) {

    var inputLayout: TextInputLayout
        private set

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.view_input_layout_wrapper, this)
        inputLayout = findViewById(R.id.til)
    }
}
```

Implementation in the view (fragment/activity):

```
private fun addNewField(fieldName: String) {
    val textInputLayoutWrapper = TextInputLayoutWrapper(
        requireContext()
    ).apply {
        inputLayout.hint = fieldName
    }

    fieldsContainerViewGroup.addView(textInputLayoutWrapper)       
}
```

**NOTE:** My app theme is not material theme, so I must add `theme="@style/AppThemeMaterial"` in the root `ViewGroup` of the `TextInputLayout`.

```
<style name="AppThemeMaterial" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```