# Set different style for each text view inside a custom relative layout view

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view, android-theme, android-styles

I have created a custom view with multiple child text view and image view. Each child view has its own style. But I am struggling to set the custom style to these child views programmatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/info_box_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/info_box_item_title_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_box_item_title"
            style="@style/InfoBoxTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxWidth="150dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_box_item_description"
        style="@style/InfoBoxDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxWidth="150dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_box_item_extra_detail"
        style="@style/InfoBoxExtraDetail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxWidth="150dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_base"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/info_box_item"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/info_box_item"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right"
    android:tint="@color/white"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I have created the three styles `InfoBoxTitle`, `InfoBoxDescription`, `InfoBoxExtraDetail`.

```
public class InfoBoxItemView extends LinearLayout {
RelativeLayout parent;
TextView title, description, moreDetail;
Context mContext;
ImageView arrow, titleIcon;
InfoBoxItemModel infoBoxItemModel;
int titleDrawableTop;

String titleText, descriptionText, moreDetailText;

public InfoBoxItemView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public InfoBoxItemView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public InfoBoxItemView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mContext = context;
    LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.info_box_item, this, true);
    initAttributes(context, attrs,defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void initAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    final TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.InfoBoxItemView,
            defStyleAttr,0);
    titleText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.InfoBoxItemView_title);
    descriptionText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.InfoBoxItemView_description);
    titleDrawableTop = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.InfoBoxItemView_titleDrawableTop, 0);
    moreDetailText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.InfoBoxItemView_moreDetail);
    typedArray.recycle();
}

private void init() {
    parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);
    title = findViewById(R.id.info_box_item_title);
    titleIcon = findViewById(R.id.info_box_item_title_icon);
    description = findViewById(R.id.info_box_item_description);
    moreDetail = findViewById(R.id.info_box_item_extra_detail);
    arrow = findViewById(R.id.arrow);
    if (!HTTextUtils.isEmpty(titleText))
        setTitle(titleText);
    if (!HTTextUtils.isEmpty(descriptionText))
        setDescription(descriptionText);
    if (!HTTextUtils.isEmpty(moreDetailText))
        setMoreDetail(moreDetailText);
    setTitleDrawableTop(titleDrawableTop);
}

public InfoBoxItemView setInfoBoxItemModel(InfoBoxItemModel infoBoxItemModel) {
    this.infoBoxItemModel = infoBoxItemModel;
    setTitle(infoBoxItemModel.getTitle());

    if (!HTTextUtils.isEmpty(infoBoxItemModel.getDescription())) {
        setDescription(infoBoxItemModel.getDescription());
        description.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }

    if (!HTTextUtils.isEmpty(infoBoxItemModel.getMoreDetail())) {
        setMoreDetail(infoBoxItemModel.getMoreDetail());
        showExtraDetail(true);
    }

    if (!HTTextUtils.isEmpty(infoBoxItemModel.getResourceName())) {
        int resource = Utils.getDrawableResource(mContext, infoBoxItemModel.getResourceName());
        setTitleDrawableTop(resource);
    }

    parent.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    return this;
}

public void setTitleDrawableTop(@DrawableRes int resource) {
    if (resource == 0) {
        return;
    }
    titleIcon.setImageResource(resource);
}

public void showArrow() {
    arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void hideArrow() {
    arrow.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title.setText(title);
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description.setText(description);
}

public void setMoreDetail(String moreDetail) {
    this.moreDetail.setText(moreDetail);
}

public void showExtraDetail(boolean show) {
    if (moreDetail == null)
        return;
    if (show)
        moreDetail.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    else
        moreDetail.setVisibility(GONE);
}

public boolean isExtraDetailVisible() {
    if (moreDetail != null)
        return moreDetail.getVisibility() == VISIBLE;
    else return false;
}
}
```

Now if someone creates and initialize `InfoBoxItemView` dynamically then how would he customize those three child text view (title, description, moreDetail) dynamically.

Comment: take a look at this it's relevant to your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code

Comment: I want to set the style for those child views at the time of initializing. So that other developers can set their style.

Answer (score 0):

Make Getter and Setter For each One

For Example  I have this Custom View

```
public class ChartLineView extends FrameLayout {
    LineChart canvas;
    TextView box;
    TextView viewTitle;
}
```

and In **init** Function

```
 box = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.box);
 viewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_chart);
```

then Set Setter And Getter

```
 public LineChart getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }

    public void setCanvas(LineChart canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public TextView getBox() {
        return box;
    }

    public void setBox(TextView box) {
        this.box = box;
    }
```

Now I can Control them

```
 barView.getBox().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
 barView.getmViewTitle().setText(getString(R.string.pedometertracker_title));
        barView.getmViewTitle().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```